# ui-select - make the arrow be on the left side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, direction, ui-select

I'm using the [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) select-box for angularJS, and I need the arrow of the select-box to be on the left side to match other select-boxes I have and the whole `rtl` direction of the site.

The arrow appreas on the right side in all the examples I'd found. I tried setting the `direction` and the `float` properties but nothing worked.

I'm using the `bootstrap` style for the ui-select select-box. And in the "real" bootstrap select-boxes it's really easy to move the arrow to the left, simply by setting `dir="rtl"`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here's an [official example](http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview) so that you can play with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reset the `right` and set `left` like this

```
.ui-select-bootstrap .ui-select-toggle > .caret {
   right: initial;
   left: 10px; /* or any other value - it should be the same as the original right value */
}


.ui-select-bootstrap > .ui-select-match > .btn {
    text-align: right !important;
    direction: rtl;
 }


 .ui-select-bootstrap > .ui-select-match > .btn > span.pull-left {
     float: right !important;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I know it doesn't appear in my question but how do you make the text inside the select-box be `rtl`?

Comment: It really helps! Just a few more things: 1. Is there a way to make the arrow shape the same as in bootstrap? I noticed now that the arrows are different. 2. For some reason the box goes grey when I'm hovering. How do I remove this? I guess the bootstrap style isn't so bootstrap...

Comment: @EllaShar - It would be best if you create a plunker with a new answer. It's very difficult to track your requirements when they are listed in the comments

Comment: Done! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407218/how-to-make-the-ui-select-more-bootstrap